# Regex for (see question)?

Tags: .net, regex

Here is an easy one :) on REGEX

I have this regex

```
"^\\$?(\\d{1,3},?(\\d{3},?)*\\d{3}(\\.\\d{2})?|\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{2})?|\\.\\d{2}?)$"
```

which works on {100, $100, $100.15, $1,000, $1,000.15} and so on....

I want a simple Regex which works on numbers like : {100, 100.15} and thats all - no commas and currency symbols crap...

Thanks,

Voodoo

Comment: also where can I test it, any good links

Comment: it is a field to enter in Amount...so any numbers with an option to enter in two decimal points.

Comment: There are different flavours of regular expressions.  While there is a common subset, sometimes you require certain features (lookbehinds, for example) which are flavour-specific.  Therefore, it's a good idea to state what flavour you are using (.NET, PCRE, JavaScript) when asking a regular expressions question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(\d+(\.\d{2})?|\.\d{2})$
```

- `\d+` one or more digits
- `(\.\d{2})?` optional decimal part
- `|` or
- `(\.\d{2})` or just the decimal part

If you make the integer part `\d*`, the regex will match an empty string.

If you can use look ahead, you can use it to make sure that the string is not empty.

```
^(?=.)\d*(\.\d{2})?$
```

Comment: I'd personally use `(?!$)` and `\d\d`.  Explanation gets you my vote.  (Any non-trivial regexp deserves comments.)

Comment: `(?!$)` sounds better than `(?=.)`. I considered `\d\d` but went for `\d{2}` as it had `2` in it - thought it reads better.

Comment: in my original question I had to use escape char "\" because it was in csharp code, do you fellows know of a better way to put this in csharp code without the escape character?

Comment: @VoodooChild, Use verbatim string literals: `@"^(\d+(\.\d{2})?|\.\d{2})$"` (including the `@`).

Comment: Thanks guys :)  (verbatim string I forgot that word before, thanks)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"
```

This will match a number followed by an optional decimal point and 1 or two decimal places.